# Why can my debian/testing system not find libgcc_s.a

Tags: c, gcc, linker, debian

I have an ultra-simple C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
  printf("This is a C program\n");
}
```

which does not compile, yielding the error:

```
cc main.c
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Compilation exited abnormally with code 1 at Sun Oct 30 01:42:10

Comment: Does [this](http://rbrusu.com/usrbinld-cannot-find-lgcc_s.html) help ?

Comment: Yes it does. I wish you had written a response, so I could mark it as an answer.

Comment: No worries, I learned something. Just post an answer with conclusions (try to stuff as many keywords as possible) and accept it yourself. Hopefully it will help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo ln -s /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 /lib/libgcc_s.so
```

Per [this post](http://rbrusu.com/usrbinld-cannot-find-lgcc_s.html) this works great!